# keep dataframe numeric after concatenation

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, concatenation

Is there a way to keep the resulting dataframe numeric after concatenating a numeric dataframe and an empty dataframe?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2],[3,4]], columns=['a','b'], index=[0,1])
df1.dtypes
Out[25]: 
a    int64
b    int64
dtype: object

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['c','d'])
df2.dtypes
Out[27]: 
c    object
d    object
dtype: object

df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1)
df
Out[28]: 
   a  b    c    d
0  1  2  NaN  NaN
1  3  4  NaN  NaN
```

I would like that the added rows are np.nan and the dataframe numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `dtype` parameter to `float`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['c','d'], dtype=float)

df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1)

print (df)
   a  b   c   d
0  1  2 NaN NaN
1  3  4 NaN NaN

print (df.dtypes)
a      int64
b      int64
c    float64
d    float64
dtype: object
```

Or cast empty `df` to `float`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2.astype(float)], axis = 1)
print (df)
   a  b   c   d
0  1  2 NaN NaN
1  3  4 NaN NaN

print (df.dtypes)
a      int64
b      int64
c    float64
d    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: This looks like a `pandas` bug to me, those elements are in fact `float` so why they have `object` dtype is incorrect IMO +1